# WSO2 APIM 2.6.0, pkix path building failed unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0 setup which was working fine. It's certificates got expired so I updated it with new valid certificates.

I have followed these steps:

1) Imported `wso2carbon.jks` certificates via carbon web page

2) Added `client-truststore.jks` certificate manually via keytool

3) Restarted the server

After that, I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.flush(TIOStreamTransport.java:161)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.send_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:104)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:95)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:47)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:750)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.flush(TIOStreamTransport.java:159)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
```

These certificates have been updated in the past multiple times and they worked fine but this time I am experiencing this error.

In `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml`, the parameter `HostnameVerifier` is already set to `AllowAll`.

Comment: Can you explain step 1?

Comment: I logged in to WSO2 carbon. In the navbar, there is an option named "keystores" under 'Manage' header. I have added the certificate from there and in the 'list', it showing a valid certificate.


P.S.: I have also added the same certificate manually from the backend but got the same error everytime